# show fortran function names in svn diff

Tags: svn, fortran

I've learned that if I place
*.f90 diff=fortran
in ~/.config/git/attributes, then git diff shows fortran subroutine/function names in the hunk headers.

Do you know how to achieve this for svn diff?

There is a svn option -x -p for C functions, but I haven't figured out a corresponding option for fortran.

Thanks

Comment: Huh, TIL something about git.

Comment: ask at users@ SVN mailing list http://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion bahrep, I've done so.I'll report back.