# Function context in git diff for fortran?

Tags: git, git-diff

`git diff` tries to provide context on the function, which a change is associated with, displaying the function name in the `@@` header line. Alternatively, the whole function can be shown with the `-W, --function-context` flag.

However, this doesn't seem to work for Fortran.

Is it possible to make git aware of Fortran with respect to this feature? Maybe a regular expression for recognizing relevant lines?

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" - given what input code, saved under what file name, and with what undesired result? what _does_ it show instead?

Comment: There is a suggestion to try for git here: [show fortran function names in svn diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062339/show-fortran-function-names-in-svn-diff)

Comment: Sure, why not - thanks!

Comment: There was a very recent update to Git's built in Fortran patterns, which should be in the next release (2.30). The `diff=fortran` setting is shorthand for using these built in patterns, which do work for most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, posted by `K. Lindsay` as background for their question [show fortran function names in svn diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062339/show-fortran-function-names-in-svn-diff). They knew the trick for Git but wanted same for SVN. I've added backticks to format code, but wording is verbatim:

> I've learned that if I place `*.f90 diff=fortran` in `~/.config/git/attributes`, then `git diff` shows fortran subroutine/function names in the hunk headers.

`kdb` says this seems to work for them too, so it seems still to be the way to do it! :-)